# Prove that the radius of convergence of $ f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^4+2021)^2+16} $ is finite

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, taylor-expansion

Prove that the function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$,
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^4+2021)^2+16}
$$
can be represented as a real power series in a neighbourhood of any $x_0\in \Bbb R$, but for each $x_0$, the radius of convergence is finite.

Most of the times we convert equations by changing scale and origin and then using power series representation of $\frac 1z$ we derive the power series representation but this is a question of complex analysis and I think there is some trick that I am not getting. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex function $f$ with
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^4+2021)^2+16} $$
is meromorphic on $\mathbb C$ and has eight simple poles $z_i$ with nonvanishing imaginary part. Thus it is analytic everywhere else, in particular on the real line, and for all $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ the radius of convergence is the distance from $x_0$ to the nearest complex pole:
$$R_{x_0} = \inf_{z \in \{z_i\}} |x_0 - z|< \infty. $$

Answer (score 4):

That's an analytic function (it's the quotient of two analytic functions) and therefore, yes, it is the sum of its Taylor series centered at each $x_0\in\Bbb R$. But the radius of convergence cannot be greater than the distance from $x_0$ to the singularities of $f$ which are located at the fourth roots of the numbers of the form $-2021\pm4i$.